# How do you remove the "shipping to" address when you send an invoice in PayPal?

Tags: paypal

I'm sending someone an invoice for contract work, and when they try to pay it, it asks for their shipping address. How do I remove this requirement? In this case, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the "Items will be shipped to" checkbox shown below. It only shows up *after* you add a customer to bill to.

[image]